# How to add noNamespaceSchemaLocation to root element of xml using xmlwirter

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a serialized object of xml and i want to add **xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation** to root element and i am using xmlwriter.

I want my xml to like like below example.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="abc.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <child>false</child>
 </root>
```

WriteStartElement won't work for me because it will create another root element in final xml after writing the fileWriter object.

**fileWriter.WriteStartElement("root");

     fileWriter.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", null, "abc.xsd");**

I extended the partial class which xsd.exe generated for my xsd and added one more member in my class

```js
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName="noNamespaceSchemaLocation",Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
public string noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "abc.xsd";
```

and now output was-

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root p1:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="abc.xsd" xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <child>false</child>
</root>
```

I want xsi in place of p1.I found that it may be because of invalid attributes of XmlAttribute but couldn't figure out what.

Working with XMLDocuments is not an option as i want to use xml serialization.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p1 prefix was added due to empty namespace. It worked when i removed the default namespace from xml and now xsi prefix is getting added when i write partial class.